# Will I still be able to log in with my google account after April 20, 2015?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid, google-openid

When signing into the new winterbash site, Google notified me that the site was using Open ID 2.0 and that [support for it is going to be dropped in the near future](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6135882).

Is this something I need to worry about? Should I start logging on with alternate accounts?